# Statically link the libcurl library to my project (a dll) in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-c++, libcurl, static-linking

So I've been trying to statically link the libcurl library to my project for the past DAY and I'm literally pulling my hair out. Everywhere on the internet different instructions are given and none seem to work. I've never statically liked a library before but now I have to (for the sake of keeping things organized).

So my project is a .dll file, which requires the libcurl library to function. I've managed to build a libcurl.lib file from the libcurl source, but I have no idea what I need to do with the properties of my dll project. I've tried adding it to "Additional library directories", "Additional include directories", "Additional dependencies" all without success. Some configurations seem to work, but in the end it still doesn't link statically, only dynamically. Oh, and I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Does anyone have any experience statically linking libcurl? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "Additional dependencies" is the way to go. If you say your DLL still depends on libcurl DLL after that, then the .lib file you have is an import library for the latter DLL after all, not a static library.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Alright, so I've cleared my settings (library dependencies, include directories) and added "libcurl.lib" to additional dependencies. Now the interface shows an error where i do: `#include "curl/curl.h"`. The error is: `error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'curl/curl.h': No such file or directory`. How do I go about fixing this? What do I need to add and where? Thanks!

Comment: `Project > Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories`. List a directory there that's the parent of a directory named `curl`, which in turn contains a file named `curl.h`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Alright, I've done that and now it builds fine. However when I try to start the program it still complains that "libcurl.dll" can't be found, while it should now clearly be included. I've got "libcurl.lib" in the additional dependencies and the folder containing the curl directory in the "Additional Include Directories". Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is the problem that `libcurl.dll` can't be found, or that it's required at all? I thought it was the latter, but your last comment makes it sound like the former. If it's "not found" what bothers you, copy `libcurl.dll` to the same directory where your EXE is (usually, ProjectName\Debug or ProjectName\Release).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yeah that was the setup I was using initially. What I'm trying to do is make it so my DLL is independent of the other library (so that I end up with just one file). The users of the file will have to copy it manually so the less files the better. Thus I want to link libcurl as a static library so it is included within the dll that is generated from my project. So I start with libcurl.lib and my project files and I end up with myproject.dll. Hope that clears things up!

Comment: There are two types of files, both unfortunately having `.lib` extension. A static library contains actual code; when linked, that code physically becomes part of the executable (EXE or DLL) it's linked with. An import library doesn't contain any code, just references to functions exported from a companion DLL; when linked, the executable takes a dependency on said DLL. As far as I can tell, `libcurl.lib` you have is of this latter variety - an import lib.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Hmm, okay thanks that makes sense. The configuration type of the libcurl source project was set to "Static library (.lib)" so that's what got me confused. How would I configure that project to generate a static library instead then?

Comment: That *is* in fact how you build a static library. Make sure you are linking to the correct .lib file - chances are, when you've downloaded pre-built `libcurl.dll`, it came together with `libcurl.lib` import library, and perhaps that's the one the linker is picking up. How to tell them apart: a static library is typically large, about the same size as the DLL or even larger, while import library is a fraction of the size. If you do in fact have two of them, try renaming the smaller one, to make sure you aren't inadvertently linking with it.

Comment: Another approach: set up both your DLL project and the libcurl static lib project as two projects under the same solution. Make the former depend on the latter (Project > Project Dependencies). Then you wouldn't need `"Additional dependencies` setting - the DLL project will automatically pick up the LIB file built by the static lib project.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks for all your suggestions! You were right all along, and I've managed to fix it. See my answer for what I did. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of experimenting I finally figured it out:
I had to do exactly this (for anyone else experiencing these issues):

1. Open properties
2. Go to Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories

   3. Add the location of your curldownload/lib folder to "Library Directories"
3. Go to Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General

   5. Add the location of your curldownload/include folder to "Additional Include Directories"
4. Go to Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input

   7. Add this to "Additional Dependencies": libcurl.lib;ws2_32.lib;wldap32.lib;advapi32.lib;kernel32.lib;comdlg32.lib
   8. Add "libcmt.lib" to "Ignore Specific Default Libraries"

And then it compiled. Hope that helped!